# AJAX : How to save data from dynamic created table rows into database?

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax button click to generate the table row for user to input data and the problem is i can't get the value when it push into the array

Here is the button click to generate the table row

```
 $('#addWEduc').click(function(){
    $('#empEduc').append('<tr align="center"><td><input type="text" name="insti[]" id="insti" style="width:98%"/></td><td><select name="lvl[]" id="lvl" style="width:98%"><option value="bach" >degree</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="course[]" id="course" style="width:98%"/></td><td><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{4}" placeholder="example : 2000" name="yrGrad[]" id="yrGrad" style="width:98%"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="EducR"/></td></tr>');
```

This the button click to save the data into database

```
$('#btnAddEmp').click(function(){
var rowCount = $('#empEduc tr').length;
        var dataString = [];
        dataString.length = rowCount - 1;
        for(var i=1;i<rowCount;i++)
        {
            var txtrow1 = $('#insti'+(i-1)).val();
            var txtrow2 = $('#lvl'+(i-1)).val();
            var txtrow3 = $('#course'+(i-1)).val();
            var txtrow4 = $('#yrGrad'+(i-1)).val();

            dataString[i-1] = [txtrow1,txtrow2,txtrow3,txtrow4];
        }
        $.ajax({type:"POST",url:"function/Function_AEmp.php",data:{"data":dataString}});
});
```

And this one is the function to save into my database

```
$data = strtoupper(trim($_POST['data']));

foreach($data as $value){
    $txtrow1 = $value['0'];
    $txtrow2 = $value['1'];
    $txtrow3 = $value['2'];
    $txtrow4 = $value['3'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbledubg (IC,Institution,Certi,Course,GradYear) VALUES('988',$txtrow1,$txtrow2,$txtrow3,$txtrow4)";

    mysqli_query($sql,$conn);
}
```

For the testing i tried and found that the value as txtrow1 and other 3 are undefined inside the array... 
I think the function i need is how to get the value i type in dynamic table rows and push into array to save into database with using ajax

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: The data i key in the dynamic table row didnt save into the database, i try to alert the array but all inside show undefined

Comment: i think is the button click to save data part got some problem

Comment: side note: in your `$('#empWork').append()` you are adding duplicate id's -> `id="orga"`, `id="jobPos"`, etc. Also, what does that function have to do with your 2nd one, as that is for `#empEduc` not  `#empWork` -> `$('#empEduc tr').length`

Comment: oh... apologize about that i didn't recognize that i give the wrong append function....  since i got 2 different tables to add row... so that is just the id for the different table...

Comment: Your selector is `#insti'+(i-1)`, but your id is `id="insti"`. You need to modify your `$('#empEduc').append()` to append the # to the `id="insti"`, ie `id="insti'+i+'"`

Comment: Ok, i will give it a try

Comment: sorry, but i had tried to change my id in the way you suggested but it didn't work and the value inside still undefined as well...
fortunately, i know wheres the problem i need to solve... 
thanks for the help :)